# Why I am able to view only final over list in the overs list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, nested-lists

There is a program to create an cricket match score card which has only two overs match . So I would like to present each single over score in one list and overall two overs in another list. For ex:[[1,0,0,4,2,6],[2,4,0,1,0,6]]. But my code is executing as [[2,4,0,1,0,6],[]].which means one over score is missing. If I comment the line 9(new_over = list()) and copy line 9 after line 10(overs.append(new_over),I get the exact or correct output. Please solve my doubt that shouldn't I write (new_over = list()) at line 9 to get the desired output.

```
import random
runs = random.choices([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                      weights = [30, 30, 20, 5, 10, 0, 5], 
                      k = 12)
overs = list()
new_over = list()
for ball, run in enumerate(runs):
    new_over.append(run)
    print(new_over)
    if (ball + 1) % 6 == 0:
        new_over = list()
        overs.append(new_over)
        print(overs)
```

Comment: Please provide your expected and actual output and reasoning behind it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You reversed two lines of code :)

```
import random
runs = random.choices([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                      weights = [30, 30, 20, 5, 10, 0, 5], 
                      k = 12)
overs = list()
new_over = list()
for ball, run in enumerate(runs):
    new_over.append(run)
    if (ball + 1) % 6 == 0:
        overs.append(new_over)  # here
        new_over = list()  # and here 

print(overs)
```

You were deleting the list before appending to it.

Hope it clarifies everything.

Have a nice,

Gabriel